# HQL query with @JoinCoumn mapping returns object[] instead of Object

Tags: hql, eclipse-emf, emf, teneo

I have this HQL query:

`from Usergroup as us join us.user`

where Usergroup and User are both types. But when the data is fetched. It returns an `ArrayList` that contains Object[] that cotnain the Usergroup and the corresponding User.

Where as with `from Usergroup` returns an `ArrayList` of Usergroup objects...

Is there a way that I can return the former query as just an ArrayList of Usergroup objects like the latter query, I don't know why it returns an object array like that...?

Comment: I don't really mind whether I get the data from the second table, the purpose of the join was get all of the users for a user group, yes you are right I could do that with a where clause instead...but is there a way to get an ArrayList containing Usergroup Objects instead of Object arrays containing both? it would be nice to know... I don't know what happened to the comment above this that I replied to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select more than one "thing", Hibernate will give you an array.

If you don't specify what you want to select from a join of two entities, it will give you both.

Try

```
select us from Usergroup as us join us.user
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer when the timer lets me, perfect, works great, In my mind I thought selecting all was the same as selecting "us" but then I forgot that this is working with objects not table properties.